# A list of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, homology-cohomology

Let $P_a(k_1,\ldots,k_n)$, $a=1,\ldots,n$ be a list of polynomials in real variables $k_1,\ldots,k_n$ such that

$$
\sum_{a=1}^n k_a P_a(k_1,\ldots,k_n) = 0
$$

Is it true that there exists a list of polynomials $P_{ab}(k_1,\ldots,k_n)$, $a,b=1,\ldots,n$ such that $P_{ab}+P_{ba}=0$ and

$$
P_a(k_1,\ldots,k_n) = \sum_{b=1}^n k_b P_{ab}(k_1,\ldots,k_n) .
$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and you can prove it concretely by induction of the total number of monomials. If some $P_a$ has a monomial $c\mathbf k^{\mathbf p}=ck_1^{p_1}\dots k_n^{p_n}$ with non-zero coefficient, then by the first condition some other $P_b$ has a monomial with non-zero coefficient, $c'k_ak_b^{-1}k^{\mathbf p}$ (necessarily with $p_b>0$). Subtract $c\mathbf k^{\mathbf p}$ from $P_a$ and add $ck_ak_b^{-1}k^{\mathbf p}$ to $P_b.$ This gives a modified list $P'_*$ with at least one fewer monomial. Applying induction gives a suitable $P'_{**}$ for the modified list $P'_*.$ Account for the modification by adding $ck_b^{-1}k^{\mathbf p}$ to $P_{ab}$ and $-ck_b^{-1}k^{\mathbf p}$ to $P_{ba}.$

This can be interpreted as the vanishing of the first homology group of the Koszul complex associated to the polynomial ring $\mathbb R[k_1,\dots,k_n].$